# Intuition of the Surface Integral of a Real-Valued Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, surface-integrals

I'm having trouble understanding the idea of a surface integral of a real valued function $f$. I've read some of the other answers here on Stack Exchange, but they seem to be focused on the surface integral of a vector field.

If I have a surface $S$, and I'm taking the surface integral $\int_S f dA$, my understanding is that I'm finding the "volume" underneath the the surface S, analogous to how a line integral of a real valued function is finding the area underneath the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ when we traverse through a curve $C$ on the $x,y$ plane.

But I am having trouble visualizing this. It seems like I can't visualize in a 3-d plot, since $f(x,y)$ would take 3 dimensions to plot, but the surface also lives in 3-d space, so I'm not sure what it means geometrically to take the surface integral of a real valued function. Does anyone have any analogies to help withe intuition here?

**Analogies:**

Line Integral over scalar function: Walking along a path in the x-y plane, graphing f(x,y) on the z-axis. The total area underneath the "fence" carved out by the the path, and f(x,y).

Line Integral over vector field: Walking along a path in the x-y plane, and being pushed around by a mysterious force at each point. The total amount of "work" exerted on me as I walk along the curve.

Surface Integral over vector field: Placing a parachute (surface) in a region with lots of turbulence, such that the force acting on the parachute at each point is different.

**Questions:**
What's the relevant one for the surface integrals over a real valued function, similar to the ones I've provided above?
What's the geometric intuition? (i.e. what volume am I calculating)?

Comment: If you think physically, then $\int_S f\, dA$ could be thought of as a "total mass of $S$" in some sense. Suppose $f$ gives the surface mass-density . Then, integrating it with respect to area over the entire surface $S$ gives the total mass of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

What's keeping you from visualizing a volume on a surface embedded in 3d? For instance, imagine a perfect sphere centered at the core of our earth whose surface is at sea level. And imagine the surface of earth with all its mountains and deep sea trenches as the plot of a function on this perfect sphere. The surface integral of this function would be the signed volume between earth's surface and this perfect sphere (not *exactly*, since the surface integral doesn't take into account the effect that volume doesn't scale linearly with the radius, but it's approximately true as long as earth's surface remains close to that of the perfect sphere).

Comment: Is there an "exact" geometric interpretation? For example, is there some question such as "Find the volume of .... <insert some shape>" which could be answered by a surface integral on a real valued function, that would be correct? If I am not mistaken, the line integral interpretation I gave in the post of the area of the fence is exact, no?

Comment: The line integral example is also only exact if the line is in a flat surface, or if you "flatten" it and then draw the graph on top. The same goes for surface integrals, with the small but significant difference that some surfaces (like a sphere) can't be flattened without distorting their surface area, which would distort the integral. But if they are flat, then the geometric intuition above is "exact" in the sense that the surface integral will actually be the volume enclosed by the surface and the graph of the function.